# PHP error on live website

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a difficult time displaying a database table on my website. I can't execute the queries that I have on my index.php file, but I can show the table on localhost with XAMPP. I can't even execute the MySQL statement codes that I have in the file. Please help!

This is when I have the statement codes not commented out:

[image]

This is when I do have the codes commented out:[image]

I even have data in the tables that I am trying to connect to. Here is the code for index.php:

```
    <?php
require_once('database.php');

//Get Category Id
$category_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($category_id == NULL || $category_id == false) {
    $category_id = 1;
}

// Get name for selected category
$queryCategory = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categoryID = :category_id';
$statement1 = $link->prepare($queryCategory);
$statement1->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);
$statement1->execute();
$category = $statement1->fetch();
$category_name = $category['categoryName'];
$statement1->closeCursor();

//Get all categories
$queryAllCategories = 'SELECT * FROM categories   ORDER BY categoryID';
$statement2 = $link->prepare($queryAllCategories);
$statement2->execute();
$categories = $statement2->fetchAll();


//Get products fpr selected category
$queryProducts = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE categoryID = :category_id ORDER BY productID';
$statement3 = $link->prepare($queryProducts);
$statement3->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);
$statement3->execute();
$products = $statement3->fetchAll();
$statement3->closeCursor();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>My Guitar Shop</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>Product Manager</h1></header>
        <main>
            <hr>
            <h1>Product List</h1>
            <aside>
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
                            <li>    
                                <a href=".?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">    
                                    <?php echo $category['categoryName']; ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </aside>
            <section>
                <!-- display a table of products -->
                <h2><?php echo $category_name; ?></h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th class="right">Price</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $product['productCode']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['productName']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $product['listPrice']; ?></td>
                            <td><form action="delete_product.php" method="post">
                                    <!-- Delete Product -->
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['productID']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $product['categoryID']; ?>">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">

                                </form>                    
                            </td>
                            <!-- Edit Product -->                    
                            <td><form action="edit_product_form.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['productID']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $product['categoryID']; ?>">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Edit">

                                </form>                    
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
                <p><a href="add_product_form.php">Add Product</a></p>
                <p><a href="category_list.php">List Product</a></p>
            </section>
        </main>
        <hr>
        <footer><p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> My Guitar Shop Inc</p></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Removed php of my username and password in database.php for security purposes:

```
    <?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=mysql.cit336.fullerview.net;dbname=cit336my_guitar_shop1';


try {
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  include('database_error.php');
  exit();
}
?>
```

UPDATE:
A kind soul helped me with my first problem, but as I have edited the file, the problem is still within the statements. Its almost like the site wants me to remove the SQL statements but I don't want to remove them. They are vital to the site.

UPDATE 2:

I have edited the database.php file to get the PDO exceptions working. But now, as I am getting closer to my goal, I get an access denied error.

[image]

UPDATE 3:

I was able to access the database. Thank you all for your help, it is much appreciated. I just made a password typo and a database typo, again thanks for all of your help!

Comment: What is `$hostname`? You don't show it. Presumably it's the line throwing the error.

Comment: Have you tried to do a print_r of the $categories array? to make sure that there is really an array there?

Comment: @RobbieAverill, it is part of the database.php file. When I had it on `$db` the fatal error would show that it was an invalid argument as well.

Comment: @HawkBlade124 without sharing it here, you are unlikely to solve your problem since it's causing your problem.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, I have updated the code to provide database.php.

Comment: There you go. Use `$link` instead of `hostname`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can we take this to chat? The bindValue is not working too.

Comment: Use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) - not both. You are using MySQLi in your `database.php` whereas you are using PDO in your `index.php`. As [Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42102767/1022914) points out below, since you are using MySQLi in `database.php`, you will need to change your `index.php` to use MySQLi as well. (Though from experience, PDO seems more easier -- so maybe you should just change `database.php` to [connect using PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-examples).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the procedural function of mysqli to connect shouldn't `->prepare` be `mysqli_prepare?`.

Also the `bindValue` is for PDO your code could be

```
$statement1 = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categoryID =?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement1, "s", $category_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement1);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement1, $category);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement1);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I am super close to showing the website. This is what I am seeing now: [link](http://www.cit336.fullerview.net/exercises/ch04_ex1en/index.php)

Comment: Well it says access denied. Something is wrong with the user, could be password missmatch, or permissions issue.Also is the port correct ? Cause i dont see port 3306 responding for that server.

Comment: It was a password typo and it was a database typo, thank you for your help!